# Tweeter oEmbed tweet type

Tags: javascript, oembed

I am trying to fit oEMbeds in my web app but I would like to know if there is a way to know what that tweet is. As far as i got this is what the oEMbed endpoint returns:

```
{
    "url": "https://twitter.com/PopularPuppies/status/1321111238579949570",
    "author_name": "Puppies ",
    "author_url": "https://twitter.com/PopularPuppies",
    "html": "<blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\"><p lang=\"en\" dir=\"ltr\">Rate this friendship <a href=\"some_twwet_url_stack_doesnt_like">pic.twitter.com/gNfukUMvp4</a></p>&mdash; Puppies  (@PopularPuppies) <a href=\"https://twitter.com/PopularPuppies/status/1321111238579949570?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw\">October 27, 2020</a></blockquote>\n<script async src=\"https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>\n",
    "width": 550,
    "height": null,
    "type": "rich",
    "cache_age": "3153600000",
    "provider_name": "Twitter",
    "provider_url": "https://twitter.com",
    "version": "1.0" }
```

The type comes as "rich" regarding of what tweet I give it